# SharePoint List Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-online

I have two different lists with different items!
 let's call them for List A and List B

I want to create a worflow that can do the following rows

when I change something in the list so must the flea throughout the List B and change all items with the same Company name like List A.

it is possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Just you should start your workflow on item change event, and add action Update list item activity.
When Item in list A get changed, update item in list B.

Comment: I have tested it but it does not change all items with the same Company name in List B

Comment: Have u added value assignment and list item for matching ? Given link might help you 
http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/workflow/use-update-list-item-action-sharepoint-designer-workflow.htm

Comment: Thanks again :)
but it only updates an item in List B , I want it to update all Items in List B, which has the same name as the Company in List A